# Angular 2 - conditional sub components for one root component

Tags: angular, components, conditional-statements

It seems to be basic problem, but i couldnt find simple solution.

I have **one root component** (something like faceted search container) **and two different sub components** which i want to use **conditionally** (depends on parameter in root component).

[Simple components diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIWNq.jpg)

These sub components are different types of search results for common root component. How to handle this situation  ? Some kind of multiple templates for one component or conditionally rendered directives of subcomponents ?

I appreciate every answer. This is my first Angular2 project so sorry if this is too trivial for someone :) .

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

If you know what component types should be added at build time, then add them to the components template and use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitchCase` to show them depending on a condition.

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchCase-directive.html

If you want to be able to pass different components from the outside to be displayed in the inside you can use

```
<ng-content>
```

or adding components dynamically like shown in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: Thank you !  For now *ngIf seems to be exactly what i needed :)